# Passing parameters to directive's parent controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've read a few questions on this and I still can't figure out how to solve this problem. Simply, I have a custom directive:

```
.directive('todoList', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                todos: '=todos',
                deleteTodo: '&'
            },
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: '/public/partials/todoList.html'           
        }
    })
```

My custom directive looks like this:

```
<todo-list todos="todo.todos" delete-todo="todo.deleteTodo(id)"></todo-list>
```

Inside my controller it looks like this:

```
function deleteTodo(id) {
        console.log(id) // undefined                
        todoService.deleteTodo(id)
        .then(function(todo) {
            todoService.getTodos();
        }, function(err, status) {
            todoService.getTodos();
        })
    }

// using controllerAs
this.deleteTodo = deleteTodo;
```

My HTML for my directive is like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $index">
    <span class="item">{{todo.name}}<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)">Delete Item</button></span>
</div>
```

The problem is that `todo._id` as a parameter comes up as `undefined` when passed to the controller function in my `console.log`. However upon checking, `{{todo._id}}` interpolates correctly, so the value does exist. I know I am missing something, but I can't figure out what. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, I just solved it.

Inside my ng-click, I changed it from this:

```
ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)"
```

To this:

```
ng-click="deleteTodo({id: todo._id})"
```